# Angular Test Random Crash when I try to test interceptor

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, interceptor

I'm testing an Angular interceptor who test the refresh token before every api call

When the api response with an error the client must logout

Most of the time it works but some times i've got

> Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
>     An error was thrown in afterAll
>     HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for https://localhost:44310/api/autoauth/refreshtoken: 401 Unauthorized

and after

> Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
>     Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.

Here

```
class SubjectAuthService extends AuthenticationService {
  logout() { }
}

describe(`JwtRefreshInterceptor`, () => {
  let service: FamilyService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let authenticationService: AuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        GtagTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        FamilyService,
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: SubjectAuthService },
        { provide: 'familyTableName', useValue: 'families' },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: JwtRefreshInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    });


    authenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    service = TestBed.get(FamilyService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

  });


  it('should logOut because no current user', () => {
    spyOn(authenticationService, 'logout');

    service.fetchFamilies().subscribe();
    httpMock.expectNone(`${environment.api}/family?catalogId=0`);

    const refreshRequest = httpMock.expectOne(`${environment.api}/autoauth/refreshtoken`);
    expect(refreshRequest.request.method).toBe('POST');

    refreshRequest.flush(null, {
      status: 401,
      statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    });

    expect(authenticationService.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch the error in the subscribe

```
.subscribe(() => {}, error =>  {})
```